# Dart: Maps nested in maps

Tags: dart

I want to store various data for my app in a single place, in a map. In JS, I'd store in a JSON file, and I want to use the same sort of approach, but struggling with Dart. I can't seem to work with nested lists or maps.

Here's essentially what I want to do:

```
var items = {
  "item1": {
    "message" : "aa",
    "nested1": {
       "message": "bb",
       "nested2" : {
          "message" : "cc"
      },
    }
  },
};

void main() {

  var message1 = items["item1"]?["message"];
  print(message1);
  print(message1.runtimeType);

  var message2 = items["item1"]?["nested1"]?["message"];
  print(message2);
  print(message2.runtimeType);  

  var message3 = items["item1"]?["nested1"]?["nested2"]?["message"];
  print(message3);
  print(message3.runtimeType);  

}
```

I've been struggling to make this work in Dartpad.
**message1** works as expected, but then I can't seem to work my way *down the tree*...
Is this a shortcoming with map literals? Do I need to use constructors? Or am I missing something bigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `items` is inferred to be of type `Map<String, Map<String, Object>>`, but `Object` does not have an `operator []`.  Therefore when you eventually extract that `Object`, you will not be able to do anything with it until you cast it a more specific type.

What you probably want instead is to explicitly declare `items` as `Map<String, dynamic>` to disable static type-checking on the `Map`'s values:

```dart
var items = <String, dynamic>{
  "item1": ...
};
```

Of course, when you disable static type-checking, you are responsible for ensuring that the values you get from the `Map` are what you expect, or you will get `NoSuchMethod` or `TypeError` exceptions at runtime.  If you do want static type-checking, you should use define custom classes instead of using a blob of key-value properties.